# How to get the label value from table row when row number is known, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, label

I have a table like this-

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <label id="lbl1" value="1">Label1</label>
   <td> 
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <label id="lbl2" value="1">Label1</label>
   <td> 
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <label id="lbl3" value="1">Label1</label>
   <td> 
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
   <td>
     Some data
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that I want to alert the value of label present in the second row's first column. Assume that I don't know label id means I know its pattern like lbl1,lbl2 or lbl3.. but not exactly what it is in the second row.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't write your code for you. You should go and check out some tutorials on JavaScript and attempt it yourself and come back if you have any problems.

Comment: It's not tough. It's just why should anyone try to help when you haven't put even the minimum amount of work in to try and solve it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay to use [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cu32/2/)

```
var label = $('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').find("label").attr("value")
alert(label);
```

Comment: Its good solution but I want to alert the value of that label not the text

Comment: But there are multiple table on page . If I am using id of that table the code is not working

Comment: Then pass the table id as $('#tableId')

Comment: Thanks Working this way var label = $('#tableaa tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text();
alert(label);

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like next

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++)
   if (labels[i].id && labels[i].id.indexOf("lbl") == 0){
      //you have found the label in the first row
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can get label value by class name

`$("label[class=lblclass]").each(function() {var result=  $(this).val(); });`

(OR)
You can get the Particular Label Value by ID

```
function getlabel_value(){var result=$('#lbl1').val();}
```